# Adminhtml - NULL in saveAction() form

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, save, admin-controller

I'm creating a new admin module, when i click on save button in my form, he calls `saveAction` with all paramaters fields but he saves me NULL value. I think that the problem comes from `saveAction()` but I don't find what is wrong,

*Here is a full code, and if you see somethings wrong somewhere, the corrections are welcome:*

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml.Menu.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->_blockGroup     = 'sd_menu';
    $this->_controller     = 'adminhtml_menu';
    $this->_headerText     = $this->__('Gérer le Menu');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = $this->__('Ajouter');
    parent::__construct();
  }

}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Grid.php**

```
<?php

class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('menuGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('menu/menu')->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
          'header'    => $this->__('Id'),
          'align'     =>'right',
          'width'     => '10px',
          'index'     => 'entity_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
          'header'    => $this->__('Nom'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'name',
          'width'     => '50px',
        ));


        $this->addColumn('address', array(
            'header'    => $this->__('Adresse'),
            'width'     => '150px',
            'index'     => 'address',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Form.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form{

    protected function _prepareForm(){

        // Instantiate a new form to display our brand for editing.
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array(
                   'id' => 'edit_form',
                   'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                   'method' => 'post',
            )
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        // Define a new fieldset. We need only one for our simple entity.
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'general',
            array(
                'legend' => $this->__('Informations menu')
            )
        );

        $menuSingleton = Mage::getSingleton('sd_menu/menu');

        // J'ajoute les fields éditables.
        $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(
            'name' => array(
                'label' => $this->__('Nom'),
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'address' => array(
                'label' => $this->__('Adresse'),
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'label' => $this->__('Email'),
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => true,
            ),
            'photo' => array(
                'label' => $this->__('Photo'),
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => true,
            ),

        ));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * This method makes life a little easier for us by pre-populating
     * fields with $_POST data where applicable and wrapping our post data
     * in 'brandData' so that we can easily separate all relevant information
     * in the controller. You could of course omit this method entirely
     * and call the $fieldset->addField() method directly.
     */
    protected function _addFieldsToFieldset(
        Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset $fieldset, $fields)
    {
        $requestData = new Varien_Object($this->getRequest()
            ->getPost('menuData'));

        foreach ($fields as $name => $_data) {
            if ($requestValue = $requestData->getData($name)) {
                $_data['value'] = $requestValue;
            }

            // Wrap all fields with brandData group.
            $_data['name'] = "menuData[$name]";

            // Generally, label and title are always the same.
            $_data['title'] = $_data['label'];

            // If no new value exists, use the existing brand data.
            /*if (!array_key_exists('value', $_data)) {
                $_data['value'] = $this->_getMenu()->getData($name);
            }*/

            // Finally, call vanilla functionality to add field.
            $fieldset->addField($name, $_data['input'], $_data);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the existing brand for pre-populating the form fields.
     * For a new brand entry, this will return an empty brand object.
     */
    protected function _getMenu()
    {
        if (!$this->hasData('menu')) {
            // This will have been set in the controller.
            $menu = Mage::registry('current_menu');

            // Just in case the controller does not register the brand.
            if (!$menu instanceof
                    Menu_Model_Menu) {
                $menu = Mage::getModel('menu/menu');
            }

            $this->setData('menu', $menu);
        }

        return $this->getData('menu');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Tabs.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Edit_Tabs extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tabs {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('menu_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle('Informations');
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->addTab('form_section', array(
            'label' => 'A propos',
            'title' => 'A propos',
            'content' => $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu_edit_tab_form')
                ->toHtml()
        ));

        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Tab/Form.php**

```
<?php 
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('menu_form',
            array('legend'=>'Social network'));
        $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text',
            array(
                'label' => 'Facebook',
                'class' => 'required-entry',
                'required' => false,
                'name' => 'facebook',
            ));

        if ( Mage::registry('menu_data') )
        {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry('menu_data')->getData());
        }

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container {

    protected function _construct() {

        $this->_blockGroup = 'sd_menu';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_menu';
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', 'Sauvegarder');
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', 'Supprimer');

        $this->_mode = 'edit';

        $newOrEdit = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')
            ? $this->__('Edit')
            : $this->__('New');
        $this->_headerText =  $newOrEdit . ' ' . $this->__('Menu');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/controllers/Adminhtml/MenuController.php**

```
<?php

class Sd_Menu_Adminhtml_MenuController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function indexAction() {
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('menu1/menu')
        ->_title($this->__('Submenu1')); // for title
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function listAction() {
    $this->loadLayout()
        ->_setActiveMenu('menu')
        ->_title($this->__('Submenu2'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}


public function editAction()
{
    $menuId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $menuModel = Mage::getModel('menu/menu')->load($menuId);
    Mage::register('current_menu', $menuModel); // The add 

    if ($menuModel->getId() || $menuId == 0)
    {
        Mage::register('menu_data', $menuModel);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_setActiveMenu('menu/set_time');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb('menu Manager', 'menu Manager');
        $this->_addBreadcrumb('Menu Description', 'Ingormations');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')
            ->setCanLoadExtJs(true);
        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu_edit'))
            ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu_edit_tabs')
            );
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
    else
    {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('menu does not exist');
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }
}

public function newAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('menu1/menu');                                                            $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu_edit'))
     ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu_edit_tabs'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function saveAction()
{
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    //init model and set data
    $model = Mage::getModel('menu/menu');
    if ($id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')) {
        $model->load($id);
    }
    $model->addData($data);
    try{
        //try to save it
        $model->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Saved');
        //redirect to grid.
        $this->_redirect('*/*/'); 
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        //if there is an error return to edit
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('Not Saved. Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setExampleFormData($data);
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$mode->getId(), '_current'=>true)); 
    }
    }
}

public function deleteAction()
{
    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            $menuModel = Mage::getModel('menu/menu');
            $menuModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))->delete();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('successfully deleted');
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Menu.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Menu extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{

    /**
     * Le constructeur
     */
    public function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('menu/menu');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu.php**

```
<?php

class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Initialize resource model
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('menu/menu', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Model/Resource/Menu/Collection.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Model_Resource_Menu_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('menu/menu');
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menu>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Sd_Menu>
    </modules>
    <global>

        <helpers>
            <sd_menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Helper</class>
            </sd_menu>
        </helpers>

        <blocks>
            <sd_menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Block</class>
            </sd_menu>
        </blocks>

        <models>
            <menu>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>menu_resource</resourceModel> //the corercted add
            </menu>
            <menu_resource>
                <class>Sd_Menu_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <menu>
                        <table>wlc_sd_menu</table>
                    </menu>
                </entities>
            </menu_resource>
        </models>

        <resources>
            <menu_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Sd_Menu</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </menu_setup>
        </resources>

    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <sd_menu before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sd_Menu_Adminhtml</sd_menu>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <sd_menu>
                    <file>sd_menu.xml</file>
                </sd_menu>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <menu1 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
            <title>Menu 1</title>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            <children>
                <item1 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
                    <title>Submenu 1</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/menu/index</action>
                </item1>
                <item2 module="sd_menu" translate="title">
                    <title>Submenu 2</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/menu/list</action>
                </item2>
            </children>
        </menu1>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <menu1 translate="title" module="sd_menu">
                        <title>My Controller</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <item1 translate="title">
                                <title>Index Action</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            </item1>
                            <item2 translate="title">
                                <title>List Action</title>
                                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            </item2>
                        </children>
                    </menu1>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sd_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_menu_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="sd_menu/adminhtml_menu" name="menu"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_menu_index>
</layout>
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

**app/etc/modules/Sd_Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Sd_Menu>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Sd_Menu>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Sd/Menu/sql/sd_menu_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
Mage::log('START SCRIPT install sd_menu 0.1.0');

try {
    $this->run("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wlc_sd_menu` (
          `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` text NOT NULL,
          `photo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `position` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
          `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
          `facebook` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `twitter` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `linkedin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `instagram` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `google_plus` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
          `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
            PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    ");
    Mage::log("Script OK!");
} catch (Exception $e) { Mage::log('Script KO: '.$e); }


Mage::log('END SCRIPT install sd_menu 0.1.0');
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Where is your `Form.php` file? You need `<form...` in order to save data.

Comment: Sorry I forgot it, I added: `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Form.php` , `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Tabs.php` and `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Tab/Form.php` .look my update please.

Comment: Also, when I click on an item in the grid, there is nothing happening

Comment: print_r($data) in saveAction(); and check your data is there ?

Comment: Yes, i have all my data with a form key

Comment: look my edit.php please i just added it, it is good I keep it or I replace it with your?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't see your `Edit.php` file.

Your `Edit.php` file:

```
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'sd_menu';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_menu';
        $this->_mode = 'edit';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->setId('menu_edit');
    }
}
```

Now your `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Form.php`

```
<?php
class Sd_Menu_Block_Adminhtml_Menu_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form{

    protected function _prepareForm(){

        // Instantiate a new form to display our brand for editing.
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array(
                   'id' => 'edit_form',
                   'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
                   'method' => 'post',
            )
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);

        // Define a new fieldset. We need only one for our simple entity.
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'general',
            array(
                'legend' => $this->__('Informations menu')
            )
        );

        $menu = $menu = Mage::registry('current_menu'); //controller must return 'current_menu'

        //for editing
        if ($id = $menu->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'entity_id',
                'value' => $id
            ));
        }

        $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Nom'),
            'name'  => 'name',
            'required' => true,
            'value' => $menu->getName()
        ));


        //add other fields
        //................
        //................

        $form->setValues($menu->getData());

        $form->setUseContainer(true);

        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

Now, `app/code/local/Sd/Menu/Block/Adminhtml/Menu/Edit/Tab/Form.php`

```
protected function _prepareForm()
{
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('menu_form',
        array('legend'=>'Social network'));
    $fieldset->addField('facebook', 'text',
        array(
            'label' => 'Facebook',
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => false,
            'name' => 'facebook',
        ));

    if ( Mage::registry('menu_data') )
    {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('menu_data')->getData());
    }

    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

}

**I haven't tested but this should work.** Good luck.

Also for your grid add this function:

```
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Your controller file functions:

```
public function editAction()
{
    // 1. Get ID and create model
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $model = Mage::getModel('menu/menu');

    // 2. Initial checking
    if ($id) {
        $model->load($id);
        if (!$model->getId()) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(
                Mage::helper('sd_menu')->__('This Menu no longer exists.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_title($model->getName() ? $model->getName() : $this->__('New Menu'));

    // 3. Set entered data if was error when we do save
    $data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData(true);
    if (! empty($data)) {
        $model->setData($data);
    }

    // 4. Register model to use later in blocks
    Mage::register('current_menu', $model);

    // 5. Build edit form
    $this->_initAction()
        ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu_edit'))
        ->_addLeft($this->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('sd_menu/adminhtml_menu_edit_tabs')
        );
        ->renderLayout();
}

public function newAction()
{
    $this->_forward('edit');
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

For grid click:

```
/**
 * Retrieve Row Click callback URL
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/view', array('id' => $row->getId())); //you may need to change `id` based on your config
}
```

Comment: in Form.php I have `Call to a member function getId() on a non-object` in `//for editing
        if ($id = $menu->getId()) {
            $fieldset->addField('entity_id', 'hidden', array(
                'name' => 'entity_id',
                'value' => $id
            ));
        }`  and also in `'value' => $menu->getName()`

Comment: Inside your `editAction()` add this: `Mage::register('current_menu', $menuModel);`

Comment: Tha same error, look my editAction please, and i have also error in `'value' => $menu->getName()`

Comment: I have double `$menu = $menu` in form. Remove one. It should be `$menu = Mage::registry('current_menu'); //controller must return 'current_menu'`

Comment: Yes i knew it was a mistake and i already removed it but i still have the same errors, about `Edit.php` I left my file

Comment: That error is related to controller which is not registering `current_menu`, which is why in form it's not getting it. You can debug if your `$menuModel->getId()` returns value in `editAction()` function. If it returns then only you can register the object to `current_menu`, which will return $menu->getName().

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: Thank you, now it work's after changing some things in your update, however when I click on an item grid, nothing happening ? i have well add `getGridUrl()` in MenuController()

Comment: Check my update.

Comment: sorry, now i get Error 404, i tried to change id with entity_id but i get the same thing

Comment: Where did you add that code? it should be in Grid.php. Also check your logs for debugging.

Comment: Yes, of course in grid.php he redirect to `menu/view/entity_id/10/key/...` with Error 404

Comment: That's because you don't have viewAction() method in your controller

Comment: I can't find this one, generally what we should put on it ?, i tried to replace `$this->_redirect('*/*/view',` with `$this->_redirect('*/*/edit',` it's works but the fields are empty !

Comment: I found the issue, in `editAction()` i replaced `id` with `entity_id` in `$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('entity_id');`

Comment: So thank you for your time and you help, thanks